# Using browsersync as dev webserver combined with node app serving only api and not static files

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I'm currently using gulp webserver with following config.

```html
gulp.task('webserver', ['nodejs'], function () {
    return gulp.src(config.client)
        .pipe(webserver({
            livereload: true,
            port: 8001,
            proxies: [
                {
                    source: '/api',
                    target: 'http://localhost:3007/api'
                }
            ],
            directoryListing: false,
            open: true
        }));
});
```

So, it serves the static files and proxies request starting with /api to a nodeJs app on another port.
I want to do now the same with Browser-sync (instead of using livereload, so I want to get rid of gulp webserver), but don't find how I can configure this.
Thanks for giving some guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Ok,I found a potential solution (please comment if you have improvements)

```html
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});
gulp.task('bs', ['nodejs'], function () {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./client"
        },

        middleware: function (req, res, next) {
        var url = req.url;


        if (url.substring(0,5)==="/api/") {
            proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:3007' });
        } else {
            next();
        }
    }
    });
});
```